# How to Select or Skip Unique Rows By Pandas Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to list unique rows within a series/column and then select or 'skip' rows based on their index value.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/imdb_1000.csv')

#list unique values in genre series
df['genre'].unique().tolist()

['Crime',
 'Action',
 'Drama',
 'Western',
 'Adventure',
 'Biography',
 'Comedy',
 'Animation',
 'Mystery',
 'Horror',
 'Film-Noir',
 'Sci-Fi',
 'History',
 'Thriller',
 'Family',
 'Fantasy']
```

I understand that I can select specific rows using `df[df.genre.isin(['Crime', 'Fantasy'])]` but could I generate an index list of all the unique values within genre and then use those index values to select which ones to keep for my dataframe?

Context - Sometimes at work I have to filter out by multiple values that are easily mistyped e.g. employee names

Comment: `df['genre'].drop_duplicates()` returns a Series of the first occurrence of each unique entry. So if you added `.index` you'd then have the Index object for those unique values.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How how I drop or keep the specific genres based on index?